# What is wrong with my integral calculation?

Tags: calculus

I want to solve the integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx$ where $a>0$ is a constant

I first tried simplifying so
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}
&=\frac{1}{a+\frac{x^2}{a}} \\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}
\end{align}
which got me
\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}dx\\[6px]
&=\frac{1}{a}\left[\arctan \frac{x}{a}\right]_1^\infty
\end{align}
which is wrong, but I can't see my mistake, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Try differentiating the result to see if you get the integrand -- be sure to apply the chain rule! Alteratively: do the substitution $x = au, dx  = a~ du$ (being sure to change the limits of integration as well).

Comment: Yeah, the mistake is that $\frac{d}{dx} (\arctan \frac{x}{a}) = \frac{1}{a}*\frac{1}{1+x^2/a^2}$ due to the chain rule. Therefore, you don't need the additional factor.

Comment: That is to say, the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{a}*\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}$ is $\arctan(x/a)$, which is the more common antiderivative at $a= 1$

Comment: I see it now, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{a}{a^2+x^2}dx
&=\frac{1}{a}\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}dx\\[6px]
&=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}d\frac{x}{a}\\[6px]
&=\left[\arctan \frac{x}{a}\right]_1^\infty\\[6px]
&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\frac{1}{a}=\arctan a
\end{align}

If $a<0$, then the final step will give $\pi+\arctan a$.

Comment: you result is correct only if a is positive.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima The condition $a>0$ is in the OP’s hypotheses.